# Custom Exception skipping in spring batch job not working properly

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have to skip a custom exception (CSVFieldMappingException) from my  custom mapper FieldSetMapper of reader FlatFileItemReader in case of ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for my Spring batch job business logic.For this I have added the configuration of the job step as below.

```
@Bean
public Step step1(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                  ItemReader reader, ItemWriter writer,
                  ItemProcessor processor, @Value("${reader.chunkSize}")
                  int chunkSize) {
    LOGGER.info("Step configuration loaded with chunk size {}", chunkSize);
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .chunk(chunkSize).reader(reader)
            .processor(processor).writer(writer)
            .faultTolerant()
            .skip(CSVFieldMappingException.class)
            .skipLimit(1000)
            .build();
```

But this is not working as another runtime exception FlatFileParseException is being raised whenever I throw my custom RunTimeException. In order to fix this I have to add FlatFileParseException also in skip of above conf. But this is will ruin my other scenarios when any other exception is raised.
How can I solve this ? I cannot make my CustomException Callable instead of runtime exception as the FieldSetMapper interface do not have such implementation.

Stack trace in the above case is as follows. I could see my CustomException being changed to some other exceptions in the chain.

```
org.springframework.batch.core.step.skip.NonSkippableReadException: Non-skippable exception during read
  at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProvider.read(FaultTolerantChunkProvider.java:105) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:116) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:110) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:69) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:392) [spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306) [spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128) [spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
  at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) [spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.run(Unknown Source) [na:na]
  at com.fastretailing.catalogPlatformSCMProducer.controller.SNSController.handleNotificationMessage(SNSController.java:99) [classes/:na]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:871) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException: Parsing error at line: 1 in resource=[InputStream resource [convertcsv.csv]], input=[Name of office,STD Code]
  at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doRead(FlatFileItemReader.java:183) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:88) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader.readFromDelegate(MultiResourceItemReader.java:140) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader.readNextItem(MultiResourceItemReader.java:119) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader.read(MultiResourceItemReader.java:108) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
  at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy83.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
  at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:91) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProvider.read(FaultTolerantChunkProvider.java:87) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
  ... 88 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fastretailing.catalogPlatformSCMProducer.exception.CSVFieldMappingException: Exception while parsing CSV file
  at com.fastretailing.catalogPlatformSCMProducer.producerjob.mapper.CSVFieldMapper.mapFieldSet(CSVFieldMapper.java:64) ~[classes/:na]
  at com.fastretailing.catalogPlatformSCMProducer.producerjob.mapper.CSVFieldMapper.mapFieldSet(CSVFieldMapper.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
  at org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper.mapLine(DefaultLineMapper.java:43) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doRead(FlatFileItemReader.java:180) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
  ... 106 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
  at org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DefaultFieldSet.readAndTrim(DefaultFieldSet.java:656) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DefaultFieldSet.readString(DefaultFieldSet.java:157) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
  at com.fastretailing.catalogPlatformSCMProducer.producerjob.mapper.CSVFieldMapper.mapFieldSet(CSVFieldMapper.java:60) ~[classes/:na]
  ... 109 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Giving a look to stacktrace )probably) you have to set `FlatFileItemReader.lineToSkip=1` to skip header column

Comment: There is no header column in my file. If I set it like that what is the advantage ?

Comment: My mistake. Number of columns in first line is different expected count?

Comment: Yes. I am throwing my custom exception CSVFieldMappingException from my custom mapper.In this case it should be skipped as it is specified in config as skippable. But this is not what happening. From the stack trace could see that this is being changed to higher level exception FlatFileParseException. And I have to add this also in skippable. But that is not the requirement. I have to skip CSVFieldMappingException only.

Answer (score 0):

After a further look at `FlatFileItemReader` exception throwed from `FlatFileItemReader.lineMapper` are wrapper into a `FlatFileParseException`.
You can write your own `ItemReader`, delegate `open()` to real reader and catch `FlatFileParseException`: if `cause` of error is your `CSVFieldMappingException` throw it back or rethrow original exception.

Comment: [This is my custom reader](https://github.com/langmi/spring-batch-examples-readers/blob/master/src/main/java/de/langmi/spring/batch/examples/readers/file/zip/ZipMultiResourceItemReader.java) , Could you please help me I tried catching exceptions and checking on super.open. But it is not coming here. Please help.